# the_title() and the_permalink() won't work on AJAX calls

Tags: permalinks, ajax, get-posts, get-the-title

I've run into a strange problem.

I have a custom loop built with `get_posts` that works fine when loading the page normally:

```
<?php
    $rows = get_posts(array(
        'post_type'     => 'drinks', 
        'numberposts'   => -1
    ));
?>

<?php foreach ($rows as $post) : setup_postdata($post) ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>
    <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
    <?php the_content() ?>
    <?php the_permalink() ?>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata() ?>
```

That code sits inside its own template called "drinks.php".

Now I've set up an AJAX function/URL to fetch this template using jQuery:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_h5b_get_user_drinks', 'h5b_ajax_get_user_drinks');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_h5b_get_user_drinks', 'h5b_ajax_get_user_drinks');

function h5b_ajax_get_user_drinks () {
    include 'drinks.php';
    die;
}
```

However, when I fetch it with AJAX it seems that neither `the_title()`, `the_post_thumbnail()` or `the_permalink()` work. `the_content()` seems to work fine though.

If I `var_dump($post)` inside my loop it has all the data it should (like title, guid etc).

How can this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function h5b_ajax_get_user_drinks() {
    return get_template_part( 'drinks' );

    exit;
}
```

Comment: I think that would require me to re-structure a lot of things. My drinks.php-file actually sits in `themes/my-theme/modules/drinks.php`.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can do it like that: <code>get_teplate_part( 'modules/drinks' )</code>. :)

Comment: Wow this actually worked! Thanks a lot. One question: Can I pass a variable to the template? When I did my `include` I could simply set a variable before including but it doesn't work now obviously. Would also love an explanation as to _why_ this works - but not a normal include. Thanks again. Edit: Scratch the variable - I checked if it was an AJAX-request instead using `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']`. Would still love to know what the difference is between `get_template_part` and a normal include.

Comment: As for sending a variable you could try setting up global variable and fetching it inside you template. Or you could place a `defined( 'DOING_AJAX' )` check and then check for actions that you are performing, lastly fetching the variable with `$_REQUEST['your_var']`.

Comment: You're returning before `exit`...

Comment: @powerbuoy, if you are using a child theme `get_template_part` will pull components from the parent if necessary. `include` will fail.

Answer (score 5):

You need to delcare `$post` as global, try:

```
 global $post;
<?php foreach ($rows as $post) : setup_postdata($post) ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>
    <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
    <?php the_content() ?>
    <?php the_permalink() ?>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata() ?>
```

Most of these functions can only work (and all of them when used without parameters) inside the Loop. What this means is that the global `$post` points to the appropriate post.

**Note:** `setup_postdata($post)` doesn't do this! Hence you need to manually declare `global $post`.

The accepted answer, which offers perhaps a more aesthetic answer uses `get_template_part()`, which in turn calls [`load_template()`](http://queryposts.com/function/load_template/) via (`locate_template()`). Looking the source - this declares `$post` variable as a global, from the comments:

> The globals are set up for the template file to ensure that the WordPress environment is available from within the function.

Hence it works :).

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I declare the `$post` variable myself on each iteration of the loop. TBH I'm not sure it's best practice to create loops like this, but I read it somewhere ages ago and it's always worked for me.

Comment: Would definitely like further explanation as to why this should work.

Comment: I find it extremely strange that `the_content()` works _and_ that my `$post` variable is indeed an object full of data just like it should.

Comment: @totels powerbuoy see edit :)

Comment: Ah ok thank you. But how come it works without `global $post` when I load the page normally? (Not AJAX)

Comment: It's also puzzling that `the_content()` works without `global $post` don't you agree? Anyway, it worked with `get_template_part()`.

Comment: @powerbuoy If you follow the paper trail of functions right back to `load_template` you can see that the difference in a raw `include` versus the former is substantial. `get_template_part` (and friends), takes your **requested file** through an entire **process of initialization** passing along the KEY global variables needed to access common data and to allow certain API functions to operate correctly, `include` does not as it knows nothing of its (WP) environment. So you can use an `include` so long as you provide the necessary globals.

Comment: @powerbuoy It works without `AJAX/global $post` because its already in the context of the loop which has already setup and provided the necessary globals. An AJAX function held externally to the loop does not know of the context in which it is required so you need to tell your function, *"hey, you need this global, that global, to make this request work"*. Using `get_template_part` does this for you, otherwise you need to do it yourself. I do wonder the performance differential versus `get_template_part` and `include`, the latter may be more efficient.

Comment: @userabuser The include is probably faster, since it doesn't need to load all the WP wrappers as `get_template_part` does, but it's also not the best practice. You probably wouldn't use the usual include in the normal templating environment, so why should you do otherwise when dealing with AJAX call? `get_template_part` not only setups all the needed globals, but also runs actions, like `do_action( "get_template_part_{$slug}", $slug, $name );`. It is always best practice to use WordPress API where possible. It is also easier and more elegant. :)

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanations. TBH I really don't like the way WP is structured. Relying on so many global variables etc.

Comment: @powerbuoy - re `the_content()` working. It seems `setup_postdate()` sets up the `$pages` global (stores post content) which `get_the_content()` uses. Madness.