# Using setup_postdata() with multi-dimensional array

Tags: posts, customization

I feel like this is going to be one of those *slap yourself on the head* questions, but here it goes anyway:

I have a multi-dimensional array of data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1033
            [zip] => 27604
            [distance] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1024
            [zip] => 27615
            [distance] => 6
        )

)
```

The `id` field in each is the `post ID` and what I'm really after. What I've tried thusfar is something like:

```
foreach( $locations as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post['id']);

    echo get_the_title();

}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

with no luck. Am I approaching this all wrong - what's the best way to get that darned ID value to run through `setup_postdata()`?

I still need to reference the other data in the multi-dimensional array (`zip` and `distance`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a [similar (related) question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72831/the-title-and-the-permalink-wont-work-on-ajax-calls/72834#72834) on here recently. The upshot is that `get_the_title()` uses the `global $post` when no argument is passed. And `setup_postdata()` doesn't set that `global` (a mistake I've made before now ).

In your case, I would do the following:

```
foreach( $locations as $post ) {
    setup_postdata(get_post($post['id']));

    echo get_the_title($post['id']);

}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**Note:** `setup_postdata()` takes a post object, not ID, so if you're going to use it, use it with `get_post()`.

Comment: Appreciate the response - is there even an advantage to using `setup_postdata()` then based on how the results are formatted (since I have to pass in the `$post['id']` var in this case)?

Comment: It's not needed for just the title - but investigating the source, `setup_postdata()` sets up the `global $pages`, which `get_the_content()` uses. So if you want to output content, then yes. I would use it anyway, to avoid any confusing bugs later down the road.